# java- how to initialise session in second servlet (to get data stored by first servlet in session variable)

Tags: servlets, initialization, session-variables

I am storing a variable in session data, from a servlet where the user tries logging in to my application. Now I want to retrieve the user data from session, in another servlet in the same application.

How do I initialise the session variable in the second servlet? Taking "request" as the "HttpServletRequest" do I code the session variable as "HttpSession session = null;" or as 
"HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);"? Or is it some other way?

Note that in the application flow, the user goes to an external page from the first servlet, and from the external page he is redirected to the second servlet. (The external page basically logs in the user via oauth in Google/Yahoo/Hotmail etc).

Does this mean that I cant use session variables in this case? Do I Have to use application scoped variables?

Please excuse me if my question sounds dumb, today is only the 3rd day of my starting coding in Servlets...

Answer (score 1):

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("foo", something);
```

should work.

You can then later retrieve the data

```
Object something = request.getSession().getAttribute("foo");
```

Comment: Hello, If I want to retrieve the data later from a JSP file, then how do I get it?

Answer (score 1):

Arvind,

in JSP you use:

```
   <% Object something = request.getSession().getAttribute( "foo" ) %>
```

which of course - unsurprisingly - is extremely similar to Thilo's answer... :-)

JSP code is evaluated on the server side, so all you have to is make sure that the JSP is chained from the servlet, eg. servlet does something like a

```
   response.sendRedirect( "your.jsp" )
```

/Anders/

Comment: Anders, I am trying to implement OpenID signin, for this initially a servlet redirects to the Open ID provider's url, where user is authenticated, after that the provider redirects the user to my seecond page (Where I want to obtain session data)...I have an option of choosing between JSP and servlet for second page, I want to ask you, will I be able to receive session data that was set by the first servlet? (from where user went to open id provider)...Can I get session data with second page= servlet/JSP?

Comment: Hi Arvind, sorry for not seeing your post before now...

I'm not familiar with how the OpenID signin mechanism works, but if you are able to provide a redirect page to the OpenID-provider, would it be possible to simply tack on whatever session variables you need as GET string? I.e. redirect URL `http://yourhost/someservlet/?sessionthingy=<insert dynamically before sending to OpenID provider>`...

/Anders/